# Are there any .NET and Java libraries with table functions?

Tags: java, .net

Are there any java or .net libraries with table functions?

With "table function" I mean functions with tables as input and output parameters like:

`T3 = f(T1, T2)` , where `T1`, `T2` and `T3` are tables.

Matrix multiplication that we know from linear algebra is for example a matrix function:

```
M3 = M1 x M2 = f(M1, M2).
```

Similarly, the distribution function often used in accounting or financial planning is a typical table function. For example, distribution of costs per department further to teams.

```
CostTable = costs(department, year), KeyTable = DitsributionRatio(department, team) --> DistributedCostTable = DistributionFunc(CostTable, KeyTable).
```

Business planning tools from SAP for example offer such standard table functions like Allocations/Distributions. SAP FOX formulas are also table functions with user-defined formulas.

These are high level functions to capture general calculation patterns in applications like financial planning, or fee calculations in financial services. Without any database or any other sort of programming, just by setting parameters for available table functions (i.e. by configuration) one can do the whole calculation. That is the idea behind table functions

Comment: Hmm, you'd rather use databases. But you certainly can use a HashMap or so

Comment: Matrix multiplication that we know from linear algebra is for example a matrix function: M3 = M1 x M2 = f(M1, M2). Similarly, the distribution function often used in accounting or financial planning is a typical table function. For example, distribution of costs per department further to teams. CostTable = costs(department, year), KeyTable = DitsributionRatio(department, team) --> DistributedCostTable = DistributionFunc(CostTable, KeyTable).

Comment: Business planning tools from SAP for example offer such standard table functions like Allocations/Distributions. SAP FOX formulas are also table functions with user-defined formulas.

Comment: These are high level functions to capture general calculation patterns in applications like financial planning, or fee calculations in financial services. Without any database or any other sort of programming, just by setting parameters for available table functions (i.e. by configuration) one can do the whole calculation. That is the idea behind table functions.

Comment: Question closed? It doesn't make sense, the question is perfectly reasonable and clear. There are other questions asking for such and such libraries. I will search the answer somewhere else.

Comment: Also, you should have added those explanations to the parent question, i.e. click "Edit" and change the big question. This way everysone sees

Comment: I'll ask on Meta if we can reopen...

Comment: BTW, if all else fails you can always ask again later

Comment: This seems like a pretty simple yes/no question for those who know those libraries well (which isn't me).  voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

If your tables will contain only numbers, then they can be represented as matrices. I found out this library:

http://code.google.com/p/efficient-java-matrix-library/

Looks like exactly what you need.

Comment: No, with table I mean structured and descriptive data like DataTable class of .NET which can contain attribute fields with string or integer values. I am not looking for a library for matrix computations.

Comment: @Jakub - do you mind showing a little example of how to work it?

Answer (score 1):

```
Department No 
           D1,D2,D3....DN----finance array of N Objects[N]
           D4,D5.D6....DM----accounting array of M Objects[M]
           D7,D8,D9 ...DK-----marketing array of K Objects[K]
For each department cost per year shown in monthly basis 
 (  departemtn) finance D1= C1  C2  C3  C4      
                            C5  C6  C7  C8
                            C9 C10 C11 C12
    .
    .
    .
 (  departemtn) finance   DN=   C1  C2  C3  C4
                                C5  C6  C7  C8
                                C9 C10 C11 C12

 (  departemtn) accounting D4= C1  C2  C3  C4      
                               C5  C6  C7  C8
                               C9 C10 C11 C12
    .
    .
    .
 (  departemtn) accounting     DM=   C1  C2  C3  C4
                                     C5  C6  C7  C8
                                     C9 C10 C11 C12

(  departemtn) marketing D7=   C1  C2  C3  C4      
                               C5  C6  C7  C8
                               C9 C10 C11 C12
    .
    .
    .
 (  departemtn) marketing    DK=   C1  C2  C3  C4
                                   C5  C6  C7  C8
                                   C9 C10 C11 C12

I exactly donot know what urs clear requirement is .But,you can start this way.But,its better to use arraylist of you have different variation of objects .
```

Comment: First try to generalize the pattern of urs problem.Later you can create urs own api for solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your main options are:

- [Jama](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/)
- [Apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/linear.html)
- [EJML](http://code.google.com/p/efficient-java-matrix-library/)